# Hot to build animator blend tree in code (Unity)

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, tree, blend, animator

everyone!

Got some problem with animator. I have a model with animations made in Maya. The model is showing signs of Russian Sign Language (RSL). It's a part of a translation system from the spoken language to RSL. So I need to build animation state tree depending on input I have. Even though I can get Blend Tree from Animator, I cannot change it. I can change it only in graphic editor, but I need to do it by scripts. Does anybody have ideas how to do this?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jbXRhTqLEn8& - here is a prototype
 of my app

Comment: Usually I double click the blend tree. Then I get to the blend tree menu where I right click it and select "add motion" (I believe it's called). Then you can select the blend tree and in the inspector select which animation clip is to be played at which value.